# Repository query that uses class properties not returning expected results

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I work on a search function using a search form in Symfony 6.3.
I created a class Search.php with 2 properties: a string (that represents the name of the activity) and an array of objects (that represent an array of activities) which are used to query the database.
When I submit the form, I don’t receive the desired results.
Namely, when I search by one of the criteria – either by the string or by the array of objects (by selecting the corresponding checkboxes), I receive the correct result. However, when I use both criteria at the same time, the result is an empty array.

Here is my controller:

```
#[Route('/administration/activites', name: 'app_admin_activites')]
    public function admin(Request $request, SessionInterface $session): Response
    {
        $etat = $request->query->get('etat');
        $page = $request->query->get('page');
        $recherche = $request->query->get('recherche'); //undefined or 1

        $search = new Search();
        $activitesByEtat = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Activite::class)
        ->findActivitesByEtat($etat);
        $form = $this->createForm(SearchType::class, $search, [
            'activitesByEtat' => $activitesByEtat
        ]);
        
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $activites = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Activite::class->findActivitesByEtatSearch($etat, $search);
            $session->set('searchObject', $search);
        } else {
            $activites = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Activite::class)
                ->findAllActivites($etat)
            );
            //$search is an empty object here
            $session->set('searchObject', $search);
        }
        return $this->render('activite/index.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'activites' => $activites,
            'etat' => $etat,
            'page' => $page,
            'recherche' => $recherche
        ]);
    }
```

Here is my repository function that processes the query:

```
public function findActivitesByEtatSearch($etat, Search $search)
    {        
        $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('activite')
            ->andWhere('activite.annule = :etat')
            ->setParameter('etat', $etat);
            
        if (!empty($search->activiteString)) {
            $query = $query
            ->andWhere('activite.libelle LIKE :activiteLibelle')
            ->setParameter('activiteLibelle', "%{$search->activiteString}%");
        }

        if (!empty($search->activites)) {
            $query = $query
            ->andWhere('activite.id IN (:activites)')
            ->setParameter('activites', $search->activites);
        }

        $query = $query->orderBy('activite.code', 'ASC');

        return $query->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
```

Here is my SearchType.php form:

```
class SearchType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        /** @var array $activitesByEtat */
        $activitesByEtat = $options['activitesByEtat'];

        $builder
            ->add('activiteString', TextType::class, [
                'label' => false,
                'constraints' => new Length([
                    'min' => 2,
                    'max' =>  10
                ]),                    
                'required' => false,
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => "Saisir le nom d'activité et cliquer Rechercher"
                ]
            ])
            ->add('activites', EntityType::class, [
                'label' => false,
                'required' => false,
                'class' => Activite::class,                   
                'choice_label' => 'libelle',
                'choices' => $activitesByEtat,
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => true,
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => "Choisir l'activité"
                ]
            ])
            ->add('submit', SubmitType::class, [
                'label' => 'Rechercher',
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'main-btn active-btn-outline rounded-md btn-hover w-100'
                ]
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Search::class,
            'activitesByEtat' => []
        ]);
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return '';
    }
}
```

Here is the class Search.php:

```
namespace App\AssistClasses;

use App\Entity\Activite;
use App\Entity\Categorie;

class Search
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public $activiteString = '';

    /**
     * @var Activite[]
     */
    public $activites = [];

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public $categorieString = '';

    /**
     * @var Categorie[]
     */
    public $categories = [];
}
```

And this is my search form:

```
    <div class="row mt-4">
        {{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'action': path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'), {'etat': etat, 'page': '1', 'recherche': '1'})}} ) }}
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <h5>Recherche par activité</h5>
                    {{ form_row(form.activiteString) }}    
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <h5>Choisir les activites et cliquer sur Rechercher</h5>
                    {{ form_row(form.activites) }}
                </div>
            </div>
        {{ form_end(form)}}
    </div>
```

I assume that the problem is in the repository query. I tried many query variations (with andX, orX, XOR etc.), but none of them returned the expected results.
I use POST request to retrieve the results.

Why does the query retrieve an empty result in case when both search options, i.e. $search->activiteString and $search->activites, are used?